# Find all process which are run in specific working directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

As title, I want to find all process which are run in specific working directory.
Firstly I think I can use this approach:

1. Use `ps` to list all processes
2. Use `pwdx` for above pid list to get working directory list
3. Check the result of working directory list then compare with specific working directory.

But I think that is very clumsy, is there any better solution?

Comment: ...if it *is* "all PIDs with a given cwd" that you want, take a look at `/proc/*/cwd`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have edited my question. I still do not catch your idea about /proc/*/cwd, can you explain more? Thank you!

Comment: Frankly, the *best* approaches for this performance-wise aren't going to be native bash, but will be leveraging languages that can do a readlink operation in-process. Whether you actually care about performance is a different question, granted.

Comment: Re: catching my idea, run `ls -l /proc/*/cwd` and look at the output.

Comment: `fuser` and `lsof` can both give you access to processes by various criteria, though getting only the ones with a particular working directory directly is not possible with either as far as I could quickly determine.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the core logic in Python called from a shell function (thus requiring only one process, vs spinning up a bunch of individual tools):

```
pids_for_dir() {
  python - "$@" <<'EOF'
import sys, os.path, glob
target = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
for name in glob.glob("/proc/*/cwd"):
  if os.path.abspath(name) == target:
    print(name.split('/')[-2])
EOF
}
```

...called from your shell as:

```
pids_for_dir /tmp
```

Comment: Maybe highlight how the `split` extracts just the process ID from the path, conveniently as text. The `/proc` filesystem is a Linux-only facility, so this is not portable to other systems.